# (How) can I re-create a package after having called Symbol::delete_package on it?

Tags: perl, package

Given a small Perl library:

```
package P;

use strict;
use warnings;

print("Loading P\n");

our $k1 = 'v1';
our $k2 = 'v2';
our $k3 = 'v2';
```

I tried to write a program which loads, unloads and reloads the package to get a better understanding of how packages work in Perl:

```
# main.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Symbol qw( delete_package );

# Load module
require "./P.pm";
my @incs = sort keys %INC;
my $numSyms = keys %P::;
print("Includes: @incs\nNumber of symbols: $numSyms\n");

# Unload module & delete package
delete_package('P');
delete $INC{'./P.pm'};
@incs = sort keys %INC;
$numSyms = keys %P::;
print("Includes: @incs\nNumber of symbols: $numSyms\n");

# Load module again
require "./P.pm";
@incs = sort keys %INC;
$numSyms = keys %P::;
print("Includes: @incs\nNumber of symbols: $numSyms\n");
```

Running this program prints something along the lines of (the order in which the modules are listed by `keys %INC` may differ):

```
Loading P
Includes: ./P.pm Exporter.pm Symbol.pm strict.pm warnings.pm
Number of symbols: 4
Includes: Exporter.pm Symbol.pm strict.pm warnings.pm
Number of symbols: 0
Loading P
Includes: ./P.pm Exporter.pm Symbol.pm strict.pm warnings.pm
Number of symbols: 0
```

I.e. it appears that re-loading the library worked as intended, but the symbol table `%P::` is still empty. Why didn't it get re-populated when the library was loaded a second time? I'm trying to find a way to reload a module without using any CPAN packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `%P::` is resolved at compile-time, so it refers to the glob `delete_package` cleared and caused the symbol table to disown.

You'll get the expected output if you force the lookup to occur at runtime by replacing

```
keys %P::;
```

with

```
keys %{ no strict qw( refs ); \%{"P::"} };
```

or

```
keys %{ $::{"P::"} };
```

What this means is that it's not enough to unload a package; you need to unload code that has hardcoded reference to the package and code that imported from the package too!

Programs that delete packages (e.g. a script loader in a Fast CGI daemon) don't usually hardcode references to the packages they delete, so they don't normally run into this issue. The following is an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Symbol qw( delete_package );

use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;

sub mod_path {
   my ($mod_name) = @_;
   return ( $mod_name =~ s{::}{/}gr ) . ".pm";
}

sub load_module {
   my ($mod_name) = @_;
   my $mod_path = mod_path($mod_name);
   require $mod_path;
}

sub unload_module {
   my ($mod_name) = @_;
   my $mod_path = mod_path($mod_name);
   delete_package($mod_name);
   delete($INC{$mod_path});
}

sub get_package {
   my ($pkg_name) = @_;
   $pkg_name .= '::' if $pkg_name !~ /::\z/;
   my $pkg = \%::;
   $pkg = $pkg->{$_} for split /(?<=::)/, $pkg_name;
   return $pkg;
}

sub dump_info {
   my ($mod_name) = @_;
   my $mod_path = mod_path($mod_name);
   my $pkg = get_package($mod_name);

   my $is_in_inc = grep { $_ eq $mod_path } keys %INC;
   printf("Included: %s\n", $is_in_inc ? "yes" : "no");

   my $num_syms = keys(%$pkg);
   print("Number of symbols: $num_syms\n");

   print("\n");
}

for $mod_name ('P', 'P') {
   load_module($mod_name);    dump_info($mod_name);
   # $mod_name->run();
   unload_module($mod_name);  dump_info($mod_name);
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's interesting! If I have a subroutine `p` which is currently given a ref to a hash (i.e. it's invoked like `p(\%P::);`) and which internally enumerates the symbols, is there a way to translate the ref within `p` to a string such that any of your solutions could be used? Or would I need to adjust the callers such that they pass a string instead?

Comment: Adjust the caller to pass a reference to the right glob.

Comment: Thanks; I guess I'll have to read up on what 'glob' means in this context (I always only knew it in the context of file name matching).

Comment: The values of `%::` (the symbol table) are globs. "Glob" is short for "typeglob", and it refers to a symbol table entry, or rather a variable of that type. It is a struct that can contain a SCALAR, an ARRAY, a HASH, a CODE, etc. For example, the glob `*P::k1` (aka `$::{'P::'}{k1}`) contains `$P::k1` (`${ *{ $::{'P::'}{k1} }{SCALAR} }`), `@P::k1` (`@{ *{ $::{'P::'}{k1} }{ARRAY} }`), `%P::k1` (`%{ *{ $::{'P::'}{k1} }{HASH} }`), `&P::k1` (`&{ *{ $::{'P::'}{k1} }{CODE} }`), etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your example code gives me plenty of stuff to think about, it'll take me some time to digest it. Much appreciated!

Comment: You wrote 'What this means is that it's not enough to unload a package; you need to unload code that has hardcoded reference to the package and code that imported from the package too!' -- this means that I cannot use `$P::k1` anywhere in the code since the value of that expression is determined at compile time, i.e. it won't reflect a possible changed value set when reloading the module, right? At least my experiments suggest this is the case. Pity! I hoped that I could somehow have `$P::k1` get resolved dynamically.

Comment: Again, not an issue encountered in practice. One doesn't unload a module that's still in use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting a memory leak with the ikegami's code.  I used Test::LeakTrace and it reports some problems. Here's the slightly code which finds memory leaks:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use lib './';
use Test::LeakTrace;
use Symbol 'delete_package';

use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;

sub mod_path {
    my ($mod_name) = @_;
    return ( $mod_name =~ s{::}{/}gr ) . ".pm";
}

sub load_module {
    my ($mod_name) = @_;
    my $mod_path = mod_path($mod_name);
    require $mod_path;
}

sub unload_module {
    my ($mod_name) = @_;
    my $mod_path = mod_path($mod_name);
    delete_package($mod_name);
    delete($INC{$mod_path});
}

sub get_package {
    my ($pkg_name) = @_;
    $pkg_name .= '::' if $pkg_name !~ /::\z/;
    my $pkg = \%::;
    $pkg = $pkg->{$_} for split /(?<=::)/, $pkg_name;
    return $pkg;
}

sub dump_info {
    my ($mod_name) = @_;
    my $mod_path = mod_path($mod_name);
    my $pkg = get_package($mod_name);

    my $is_in_inc = grep { $_ eq $mod_path } keys %INC;
    printf("Included: %s\n", $is_in_inc ? "yes" : "no");

    my $num_syms = keys(%$pkg);
    print("Number of symbols: $num_syms\n");

    print("\n");
}

leaktrace {
    foreach my $mod_name ('P', 'P') {
        load_module($mod_name);    dump_info($mod_name);
        unload_module($mod_name);  dump_info($mod_name);
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Included: yes
Number of symbols: 1

Included: no
Number of symbols: 0

Included: yes
Number of symbols: 1

Included: no
Number of symbols: 0

leaked SCALAR(0x556efcaf9a90) from /home/terry/projects/robinson/dev/trunk/command-line/experiments/perl-hacks/P.pm line 2.
leaked SCALAR(0x556efcbb5628) from /usr/share/perl/5.26/Symbol.pm line 74.
```

This
seven year old suggests that the problem in a bug in Perl itself.

Does this still appear to be a bug?